# TeX capacity exceeded using Knitr

Tags: tex-core, plot, knitr, capacity

I am unable to weave a document containing LaTeX and R code using RStudio due what I think are TeX capacity limitations. Is there a way of fixing this without having to compile using LuaLaTeX which is not supported by knitr? I'd like the document to be as portable as possible. Below is a minimal code chunk (without actual data):

```
<<MyPlot, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, warning=FALSE, cache=TRUE, 
message=FALSE,include=TRUE>>=

library(ggplot2)
cbPalette <- c("#009E73", "#CC79A7")
pd <- position_dodge(0.4)

plot1<-ggplot(data=summary, aes(x=label, y=V10, colour=Adv, group=Adv)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=V10-ci, ymax=V10+ci), width=.6, position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd, size = 1) +
  geom_point(position=pd, size = 3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 25)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) +
  ylab("My y axis") + 
  xlab("My x axis") + 
  theme(legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2), "cm")) +
  facet_grid(. ~ scale) +
  ggtitle("") 
plot1
@
```

The error message I get when I compile the pdf is:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]
```

If I leave out the last line of the code above and do not require the plot to be printed, the code runs just fine.

Comment: I can't run  your code but using that much parameter stack almost always implies a loop so using a bigger tex wouldn't help, is `c("#009E73", "#CC79A7")` valid or do you need `c("\#009E73", "\#CC79A7")` as you would if typesetting those strings directly in TeX?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, the list of color hues is R code, it would never run directly in TeX. I tried running the R code with the default color options, but I get the same error.

Comment: Does the R part of your document run/work in R alone (without any LaTeX stuff)? This is to make sure that your R code isn't the problem.

Comment: Yes, I checked that and it works fine. There is no problem with the R code. Also, I can compile the Rnw document just fine if I comment the last line of the code above.

Comment: You might check if the image file for the plot you generate can be opened (in the folder _figure_ look for _MyPlot.pdf_). You could also try to add the option `dev='png'` in the `<<MyPlot, ...>>=` heading see if that changes anything...

Comment: @LucM Thanks for your suggestions. The image file can be open from the figure folder, but the problem still persists. Specifying the dev options did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @Helena [This link](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/TeX-capacity-exceeded,-sorry) could be useful (even though it concerns Matlab). In particular, I think point 4 could be an option to try.